# JTable with custom edit dialog returning complex data type

Tags: java, swing, dialog, jtable

In my application I have JTable which allows to modify data. My main type is `Painting` which can has multiple categories. So `Painting` class has a member `private Set<Category> categories`. `Category` is a simple POJO class with `String name`.
I am trying to achieve following: In my JTable I have column for categories entry. I want to display to user list of categories names. After a mouse click I want to display dialog with JList which will allow to select multiple categories.
Displaying part is easy - I have provided my custom table model and provided `getValueAt(int row, int column)` which transforms `Set<Category>` to `String`.
Now I have problem with custom cell editor. I want from editor to receive `Set<Category>` (to select categories to which already `Painting` belongs) and also return `Set<Category>` so I can substitute it in `Painting` object being edited.
Can you please give me hint how to write `getCellEditorValue` and `getTableCellEditorComponent` to achieve my needs? Now I am very confused what should they provide in return.

Also I am confused about `getTableCellEditorComponent` method parameter `Object value`. What value is provided to editor? Is this the same value which table model `getValueAt` method return? Or is it different value?

Comment: 1. After a mouse click I want to display dialog with JList which will allow to select multiple categories. == isn't something about TableCellEditor, so far away, its about separate Object that can returns a value back to XxxTableModel 2. use setValueAt as equivalent to getValueAt, and a TableCellEditor to do the same thing(s), 3. you never mentioned something about XxxTableModel, in most cases doesn't matter because DefaultTableModel is created by default, but I'd suggest to override setValueAt for DefaultTableModel too

Comment: I want to display dialog with JList which will allow to select multiple categories == simple to use JComboBox (has list, and in emergency case you can to override AbstractListModel, even I'd suggest to use MutableComboBoxModel) as DefaultTableEditor (read Oracle tutorial for working code example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this example will help:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

/*
 * The editor button that brings up the dialog.
 */
//public class TablePopupEditor extends AbstractCellEditor
public class TablePopupEditor extends DefaultCellEditor
    implements TableCellEditor
{
    private PopupDialog popup;
    private String currentText = "";
    private JButton editorComponent;

    public TablePopupEditor()
    {
        super(new JTextField());

        setClickCountToStart(1);

        //  Use a JButton as the editor component

        editorComponent = new JButton();
        editorComponent.setBackground(Color.white);
        editorComponent.setBorderPainted(false);
        editorComponent.setContentAreaFilled( false );

        // Make sure focus goes back to the table when the dialog is closed
        editorComponent.setFocusable( false );

        //  Set up the dialog where we do the actual editing

        popup = new PopupDialog();
    }

    public Object getCellEditorValue()
    {
        return currentText;
    }

    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(
        JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column)
    {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                popup.setText( currentText );
//              popup.setLocationRelativeTo( editorComponent );
                Point p = editorComponent.getLocationOnScreen();
                popup.setLocation(p.x, p.y + editorComponent.getSize().height);
                popup.show();
                fireEditingStopped();
            }
        });

        currentText = value.toString();
        editorComponent.setText( currentText );
        return editorComponent;
    }

    /*
    *   Simple dialog containing the actual editing component
    */
    class PopupDialog extends JDialog implements ActionListener
    {
        private JTextArea textArea;

        public PopupDialog()
        {
            super((Frame)null, "Change Description", true);

            textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
            textArea.setLineWrap( true );
            textArea.setWrapStyleWord( true );
            KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER");
            textArea.getInputMap().put(keyStroke, "none");
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textArea );
            getContentPane().add( scrollPane );

            JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
            cancel.addActionListener( this );
            JButton ok = new JButton("Ok");
            ok.setPreferredSize( cancel.getPreferredSize() );
            ok.addActionListener( this );

            JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
            buttons.add( ok );
            buttons.add( cancel );
            getContentPane().add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            pack();

            getRootPane().setDefaultButton( ok );
        }

        public void setText(String text)
        {
            textArea.setText( text );
        }

        /*
        *   Save the changed text before hiding the popup
        */
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if ("Ok".equals( e.getActionCommand() ) )
            {
                currentText = textArea.getText();
            }

            textArea.requestFocusInWindow();
            setVisible( false );
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        String[] columnNames = {"Item", "Description"};
        Object[][] data =
        {
            {"Item 1", "Description of Item 1"},
            {"Item 2", "Description of Item 2"},
            {"Item 3", "Description of Item 3"}
        };

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(300);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        // Use the popup editor on the second column

        TablePopupEditor popupEditor = new TablePopupEditor();
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor( popupEditor );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Popup Editor Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JTextField(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add( scrollPane );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

It displays a popup dialog. You would need to customize the `getCellEditorValue()` method to return the object that you want to store in your model.